# Free AspectJ code samples for the web

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, aspectj

I am a newbie to AspectJ and to learn it I am trying to search for some open-source simple applications that use AspectJ for the web but I am unable to retrieve any. I am trying to build a filter through this technology but I am not able to find any working examples that are suited in particular to Eclipse/Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

You can get (many variations) of a simple e-commerce application built using Spring+AspectJ from http://manning.com/laddad2 (click on "Source Code" link).

Comment: ahh, I really like to thank SO and thank you for writing "AspectJ in Action"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure they're specifically targeted at Tomcat, but the examples at 
[Eclipse AspectJ Sample code](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/sample-code.html) ought to give you a start.